# Python: A4 size for a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code that saves a figure with:

```
savefig("foo.eps", orientation = 'portrait', format = 'eps')
```

If I don't specify anythingelse, the figure is correctly saved but when I print it, the figure fills only the half of a A4 sheet.If I modify the string as:

```
savefig("foo.eps", papertype = 'a4', orientation = 'portrait', format = 'eps')
```

Nothing chages!
How can I set the size of the figure in a way that it fills the whole A4 sheet?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the figure? You should probably set the right figure size before plotting.

Comment: According to [this](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-plot-benchmark-results-matplotlib.html), `figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)` should work.

Comment: With `errorbar`. The same happens when I use `plot`.

Comment: Thanks unutbu. I thought there was an option to set A4, insted of the exact dimension of the sheet, but it is ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try to set the size of the figure (in inches) before you save it.  You can do this when you initialize the figure by doing:

```
figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27)) # for landscape
```

or if the figure exists:

```
f = gcf()  # f = figure(n) if you know the figure number
f.set_size_inches(11.69,8.27)
```

or in advance for all plots, using

```
rc('figure', figsize=(11.69,8.27))
```

Comment: For a A3 format (might be useful) :
```f.set_size_inches(16.53,11.69)```

Comment: kinda weird that we are stuck with american units on matplotlib when the rest of the world uses SI units...